# salesforce : AccountId is not able to get it form lightning component js controller, giving undefined error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, salesfoce

Comp:

```
 <aura:attribute name="ServiceRequestRecordFields" type="WorkOrder"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordEditor"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      targetRecord="{!v.ServiceRequestRecord}"
                      targetFields ="{!v.ServiceRequestRecordFields}"
                     />

 <c:customLookupComp objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.ServiceRequestRecordFields.AccountId}" label="Account Name"/> <!--  isRequired="true" AutoPopulate="true" -->
```

JS:

```
 var servicereqAccid = component.get("v.ServiceRequestRecord");
         console.log('servicereqAccid',servicereqAccid.AccountId);
```

servicereqAccid is giving Undefined error, can someone please help.. thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually load the record. You need to specify the record Id:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordEditor"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.ServiceRequestRecord}"
                  targetFields="{!v.ServiceRequestRecordFields}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordLoaded}"
                 />
```

You will also need to wait until the record is loaded (see example above).

Answer (score 1):

Your Data Service has no identifier of which record it should fetch. Add the following attribute to the  tag:

```
recordId="{!v.recordId}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have aura:attribute tag for ServiceRequestRecordFields. Do you also have one for ServiceRequestRecord? If not, you may need to add it to your cmp file.